# Serving mp3s via PHP to mobile devices

Tags: php

I have a very simple PHP script that serves an mp3 file back to the browser.
It works perfectly on desktop browsers, but unfortunately doesn't play on any of the mobile devices I've tested (Android Phone, iPad Mini). Can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
<?php
    $file = 'track.mp3';

    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=track.mp3');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

**Please note:** I'm aware that this is pointless in and of itself; this is a simplified version of a much larger application, but I've stripped out the rest of the code to provide the simplest reproducer I can.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: IMO it should be played using javascript on mobile devices. Please add the javascript tag.

Comment: what happens if you execute it on android? it should start to download the file, doesn't it?

Comment: I want to play it through the HTML5 audio player (I'll probably use [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) for this), hence why I want it to be treated as a native mp3.

Comment: @steven If I change the Content-Disposition to be `attachment` instead of `inline`, then yes, it starts to download. But that's not what I want here, I want to stream the file. With Content-Disposition as `inline`, Android loads the audio player (so recognises it as an mp3), but when I hit play it just sits at 00:00 and does nothing.